# In Ransack tutorial, app/views/products/index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I would like to take the [Ransack tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) a bit further by having the capability
to show additional information on the product when I click on it.

**`app/views/products/index.html.erb`:**

```
...
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to(product.name, product) %></td>
        <td><%= product.released_on.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Web browser shows:

```
Product Name         Release Date    Price

Settlers of Catan    June 20, 2014   $34.95

Red Shirt            August 2, 2014  $12.49
...
```

Each item under Product Name can be selected.
Suppose that each product has additional description besides product name, release date, and price and I would like to display them by changing

```
<td><%= link_to(product.name, product) %></td>
```

to

```
<td><%= link_to(product.name, product_path(product)) %></td>
```

and adding something like this in **`show.html.erb`**:

```
 <p>
    Manufacturer:
    <%= @product.manufacturer %>
 </p>
 <p>
    Description:
    <%= @product.description %>
 </p>
 ...
```

**`products_controller.rb`:**

```
...
def show
    @search = Product.search(params[:q])
    @products = @search.result
end
...
```

Doing this will give errors. What's the correct way of getting the intended results?
Hopefully this question will also benefit people who are new to ransack gem.

Answer (score 0):

Your show action is wrong. #show action should return a single object. Ransack is not recommneded here.

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

or if you want to use ransack, then

```
def show
  @search = Product.ransack(params[:q])
  @product = @search.result.first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

your Products_controller should look like this.

def index
    @search = Product.search(params[:q])
    @products = @search.result
end

def show
    @products = Product.find(params[:id])
end